# How to filter Realm objects by list

Tags: ios, swift, filter, realm

I have a `DeviceContactModel` and a `DeviceContactPhoneModel` that inherit from `Object` (Realm). The `DeviceContactModel` has a `List` `<DeviceContactPhoneModel>`. I want to filter the `DeviceContactModel` by one of the `DeviceContactPhoneModel` property. I made the test code, but it calls the app crash. Please tell me how it can be implemented? Thanks.

```
    class DeviceContactModel: Object, Mappable {

        @objc dynamic var id = ""
        @objc dynamic var givenName = ""
        @objc dynamic var familyName = ""
        @objc dynamic var updateTimestamp = 0.0

        var isNew = false

        let phones = List<DeviceContactPhoneModel>()

    }

final class DeviceContactPhoneModel: Object, Mappable {

    @objc dynamic var id = ""
    @objc dynamic var contactID = ""
    @objc dynamic var updateTimestamp = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var countryCode: Int64 = 0
    @objc dynamic var nationalNumber: Int64 = 0
    @objc dynamic var fullNumber: Int64 = 0

}
```

Test function

```
private func getDeviceContacts(_ phoneNumbers: [Int64]) -> [DeviceContactModel] {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            let deviceContacts = Array(realm.objects(DeviceContactModel.self).filter("phones.fullNumber IN %@", phoneNumbers))
            return deviceContacts
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            return []
        }
    }
```

Crash log
**Invalid predicate', reason: 'Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations**

Comment: "I made the test code, but it calls the app crash" Do you mind giving us the crash log/reason then?

Comment: @Larme I'm sorry, I updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this solution

If you use a to-many relationship, You use an `ANY` operator

Please read this well so you understand what to use because there is another operator ex `ALL,ANY,NONE`  [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)

```
 private func getDeviceContacts(_ phoneNumbers: [Int64]) -> [DeviceContactModel] {
            do {
                let realm = try Realm()
                let deviceContacts = Array(realm.objects(DeviceContactModel.self).filter("ANY phones.fullNumber IN %@", phoneNumbers))
                return deviceContacts
            } catch {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                return []
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

May you can use:

```
var numbers: [[DeviceContactModel]] = [[]]
for number in phoneNumbers{
   let deviceContacts = Array(realm.objects(DeviceContactModel.self))
   let deviceWithNumber = deviceContacts.filter({ $0.fullNumber == number })
   numbers.append(deviceWithNumber)
}
return numbers.flatMap({ $0 })
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about this approach and it works, but I thought and would like to find a solution for Realm predicate